# Google Visualization library Facets : How to save python module "facets" output html to local drive offline?

Tags: javascript, python, facet

Recently I found about python visualization library "Facets" and wondered if I can produce html outputs offline.

- I am using chrome browser and `webcomponents-lite.js` is not needed.
- Also, I have installed bazel using homebrew in my MacOS.
- I have copied "facets-dist" folder from facets official repo to jupyter path `~/.ipython/nbextensions/`

Useful Links:
- https://github.com/PAIR-code/facets
- https://colab.research.google.com/github/PAIR-code/facets/blob/master/colab_facets.ipynb

## My attempt:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML


df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[10,20],'b':[100,200]})
jsonstr = df.to_json(orient='records')

HTML_TEMPLATE = """<link rel="import" href="/nbextensions/facets-dist/facets-jupyter.html">
        <facets-dive id="elem" height="600"></facets-dive>
        <script>
          var data = {jsonstr};
          document.querySelector("#elem").data = data;
        </script>"""

html_str = HTML_TEMPLATE.format(jsonstr=jsonstr)

# write the html to a file
with open('output.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html_str)
    #f.write(HTML(html_str).data)

!open output.html
```

It creates some output.html file, but does not show any visualizatons. How create a proper output html?

Comment: I have no idea how to do that (and would be very interested in the solution !) but one way to circumvent the problem is to create a notebook, display your variable HTML_TEMPLATE and use the jupyter command line `jupyter nbconvert --to html facets-dive.ipynb`. The html file produced will then contain your vizualisation.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually possible to do it. The problem in your code comes from these lines:

```py
HTML_TEMPLATE = """<link rel="import" href="/nbextensions/facets-dist/facets-jupyter.html">
        <facets-dive id="elem" height="600"></facets-dive>
        <script>
          var data = {jsonstr};
          document.querySelector("#elem").data = data;
        </script>"""
```

you should now use this `HTML_TEMPLATE`:

```py
HTML_TEMPLATE = """<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webcomponentsjs/1.3.3/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
            <link rel="import" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PAIR-code/facets/1.0.0/facets-dist/facets-jupyter.html">
            <facets-dive id="elem" height="600"></facets-dive>
            <script>
              var data = {jsonstr};
              document.querySelector("#elem").data = data;
            </script>"""
```

The rest of you code looks fine